# Define file order in gulpfile.js

Tags: gulp

I need to run bundling and minifying for some .js files, but I need to define a correct order for these files to be processed.

How can I do this?

my gulpfile.js file, path snippet:

```
...
var paths = {
    js: webroot + "js/lib/**/*.js",
    minJs: webroot + "js/lib/**/*.min.js",
    css: webroot + "css/lib/**/*.css",
    minCss: webroot + "css/lib/**/*.min.css",
...
```

I need to process in this order:

```
jquery.js
jquery-ui.custom.js
my-site.js
```

### update

Entire gulpfile.js file (this is the default file for asp.net core bundling and minifying tasks):

```
/// <binding Clean='clean' />
"use strict";

var gulp = require("gulp"),
    rimraf = require("rimraf"),
    concat = require("gulp-concat"),
    cssmin = require("gulp-cssmin"),
    uglify = require("gulp-uglify");

var webroot = "./wwwroot/";

var paths = {
    js: webroot + "js/lib/**/*.js",
    minJs: webroot + "js/lib/**/*.min.js",
    css: webroot + "css/lib/**/*.css",
    minCss: webroot + "css/lib/**/*.min.css",
    concatJsDest: webroot + "js/site.min.js",
    concatCssDest: webroot + "css/site.min.css"
};

gulp.task("clean:js", function (cb) {
    rimraf(paths.concatJsDest, cb);
});

gulp.task("clean:css", function (cb) {
    rimraf(paths.concatCssDest, cb);
});

gulp.task("clean", ["clean:js", "clean:css"]);

gulp.task("min:js", function () {
    return gulp.src([paths.js, "!" + paths.minJs], { base: "." })
        .pipe(concat(paths.concatJsDest))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest("."));
});

gulp.task("min:css", function () {
    return gulp.src([paths.css, "!" + paths.minCss])
        .pipe(concat(paths.concatCssDest))
        .pipe(cssmin())
        .pipe(gulp.dest("."));
});

gulp.task("min", ["min:js", "min:css"]);
```

Comment: It’s entirely unclear what your `gulpfile.js` does and how it works.

Comment: Hi @poke, just update with entire gulpfile file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty simple, you need to specify array of paths to your files (paths **can** contain wildcards), i.e:

```
/* REMEMBER TO USE FULL PATHS */
var order = [
    "jquery.js",
    "jquery-ui.custom.js",
    "my-site.js"
];
gulp.task("yourtask",function () {
    var sources = order.concat([
        webroot + "js/lib/**/*.js",
        webroot + "js/lib/**/*.min.js",
    ]);
    return gulp.src(sources)./* your operations goes here*/
});
```

Also, **gulp** is smart enough to **not duplicate** already used files, so you can include your libraries like this one:
`webroot + "js/lib/**/*.js"`